# How to sort generic list in java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map `Map<K, List<V>> inputMap` I want to sort list before storing to list

```
List<String> outputList = inputMap.keySet()
 .stream()
 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
 .map(key -> (key + "==" + inputMap.get(key).sort(c);))
 .sorted()
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How is your comparator `c` implemented?

Comment: Post is not clear. Elaborate what are you trying to achieve

Comment: the most important, you must implements your comparator `c` correctly. and the code above even can't be compiled due to `List.sort` not return anything.

Comment: So you want to sort each List<V> and then join them into a bigger list?

Comment: @NickZiebert what he want is: `{b:[4,3],null:[5,6], a:[2,1]}` will output: `["a == [1, 2]", "b ==[3, 4]"]`

Comment: Yes, and my comparator is not implemented, I am confuse on that part.

Comment: @RiteshChouhan the javadoc of  [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) describing how to implements it clearly. I'm going to sleeping, see you tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
List<String> outputList = inputMap.keySet().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(key -> key + "==" 
                            + inputMap.get(key).stream().sorted(c)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**OR**

```
List<String> outputList = inputMap.keySet().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(key -> key + "=="
                            + inputMap.get(key).stream().sorted(c)
                                        .map(Object::toString)
                                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ","[","]")))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, second solution worked for me, but I changed my map to Map<K, List<String>>. but Can you help for generic type  sorted(c) comparator part

Comment: @RiteshChouhan Hi, but I still remind you that the first solution can also work fine.

Comment: Yeah its working, I have verified that also, Thanks :)